# Why pandas expanding count when axis = 1 not working

Tags: python, pandas, count

I have a dataframe like:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [0, 1, 2, np.nan, 4], 
               'B': [0, 1, 2, np.nan, 4], 
               'C': [0, 1, 2, np.nan, 4], 
               'D': [0, 1, 2, np.nan, 4], 
               'E': [0, 1, 2, np.nan, 4], 
               'F': [0, 1, 2, np.nan, 4]})
```

and I expect df.expanding(axis = 1).count to produce results like:

```
     A    B     C     D     E     F
0  1.0  2.0   3.0   4.0   5.0   6.0
1  1.0  2.0   3.0   4.0   5.0   6.0
2  1.0  2.0   3.0   4.0   5.0   6.0
3  0.0  0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
4  1.0  2.0   3.0   4.0   5.0   6.0
```

However, the results produced are the same as df2.expanding().count() would do:

```
     A    B    C    D    E    F
0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
1  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0
2  3.0  3.0  3.0  3.0  3.0  3.0
3  3.0  3.0  3.0  3.0  3.0  3.0
4  4.0  4.0  4.0  4.0  4.0  4.0
```

What did I miss here?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like `expanding` method's axis parameter doesn't work with `count()` as it's supposed to.

The workaround to this problem is to transpose the data then use expanding method with count and transpose it back.

```
df1 = df.T.expanding().count().T
print(df1)

    A   B   C   D   E   F
0   1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0 5.0 6.0
1   1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0 5.0 6.0
2   1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0 5.0 6.0
3   0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
4   1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0 5.0 6.0
```